# Python - os.getenv works in command prompt, but not in jupyter notebook? (Windows)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, environment-variables

I recently added a new system environment variable via "Edit the system environment variables" in Windows 10. If I activate python in Windows command prompt and do

```
>>>import os
>>>os.getenv('newvar')
```

It properly returns the value. However, if I go to Anaconda Prompt and do the same thing in a jupyter notebook, I get "None." Other variables work, however. How can I make this new environment variable visible in Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable may not be available in Jupyter if you started your Jupyter kernel before making the change. The follow sequence catches me soemtimes:

1. You have a Jupyter kernel always running in the background.

   1. The Jupyter kernel gets its ENV variables when it first starts.
2. You add something to the system or user ENV variables.
3. You open a CMD window, it loads the latest ENV variables and your new one is available.
4. You open a Jupyter notebook, it uses the ENV variables from #1 (not containing your latest change).

Comment: Got it now, I hadn't started jupyter before the change but I DID start Anaconda prompt. After resetting my computer it works now (I should've tried that first, haha...) Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it! Yes, Jupyter inherits the ENV variables from Anaconda Prompt (which got them when it was first started). Welcome to StackOverflow, and remember to accept the answer if it was helpful for you!